# Having Trouble getting this form to submit to netlify and the recaptcha to show

Tags: reactjs, forms, netlify

I want this form to submit to netlify and the recaptcha to show on the form i have followed the documentaton on this but it still doesn't seem to be working. The recaptcha is not showing and the form is just redirecting and saying the url is not found.

```
 <form
        name="contact"
        method="POST"
        data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
        data-netlify="true"
        className={classes.container}
        Validate
        autoComplete="off"
      >
        <TextField
          id="standard-name"
          name="name"
          label="Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <TextField
          id="Email"
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          defaultValue="Email"
          className={classes.textField}
          margin="normal"
        />
        <TextField
          id="Message"
          name="message"
          label="Message"
          placeholder="Message"
          multiline
          className={classes.Message}
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
        />
        <div>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="MyFile"
            name="MyFile"
            label="File"
            placeholder="File"
            multiline
            className={classes.Message}
            margin="normal"
            variant="outlined"
            style={{ width: '40%' }}
          />
        </div>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          type="submit"
          value="Send Message"
          className={classes.button}
        >
          Send
        </Button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Troubleshoot links for future readers:


https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-form-problems-form-debugging-404-when-submitting/92/7


https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/#troubleshooting-tips

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the form "action"> It cant find a URL because you don't have one defined in the form request.

```
<form
    name="contact"
    method="POST"
    ...
    action=“(url)"
    ...
    data-netlify-recaptcha="true"
    data-netlify="true"
    className={classes.container}
    Validate
    autoComplete="off"
  >
```

Add this line with the URL or script location.

```
action="(url)"
```

Comment: Yes but this is serverless i'm trying to send this via Netlify

Comment: And the documentation doesnt say anything about a Action URL

Comment: Interesting I saw some Netlify requests with action paths. Did you try adding an empty input field with your form name?

<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="put-name-here" />


at the beginning of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<div>` which would display the reCAPTCHA. As per [Netlify documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/spam-filters/#netlify-provided-recaptcha-2):

> To have Netlify provide the CAPTCHA:
>
> 1. Add a `data-netlify-recaptcha="true"` attribute to your  tag.
> 2. In the place where you’d like the CAPTCHA to appear, add an empty  element inside your form with the same
>    `data-netlify-recaptcha="true"` attribute.
>
> [...]
>
> ```html
> <form name="contact" method="POST" data-netlify-recaptcha="true" data-netlify="true">
>   ...
>   <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true"></div>
>   ...
> </form>
> ```